# Other kind long division help

Tags: subdividing

I need to make equations like this with 'check'. Here is my example with strange spacing. [image]
The long division is from PageMaker. I am making excel tables then I copy them in Pagemaker but its very hard to do.

Comment: Can you please provide code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: The long division is from PageMaker. I am making excel tables then I copy them in Pagemaker but its very hard to do.

Comment: So you didn't create those with TeX? Please note that this page is not a do-it-for-me service. Questions about more specific things tend to get answered quicker and better. There are packages tackling that. One example could be `longdivision`, with it you can do `\longdivision{402}{3}`, but I personally dislike the output of that package. Another example would be `polynom` which adds `\longdiv`.

Comment: I have used xlop, longdiv, but it's just other kind of long division.

Comment: [link] (https://imgur.com/a/oMBKXnQ) I want it like that, those packages does offer different things.

Comment: If there's more to so, saying so is good.  If Segletes has solved this one for you, a fitting thing to do is click the "check mark" for his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way, if you prefer to retain column gaps:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[TABcline]{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
\newcommand\lminus{\llap{$-$}}
{\catcode`-=\active
\gdef -{\lminus}}
\newcommand\minusactive{\phantom{-}\catcode`-=\active}
\setstacktabbedgap{3pt}
\begin{document}
$
\minusactive
\tabbedShortunderstack[r]{
 &3&7&0&5&:5=741\\
-&3&5& &&\\
\TABcline{2,3}
 & &2&0&&\\
 &-&2&0&&\\
\TABcline{3,4} 
 & & & &5&\\
 & & &-&5&\\
\TABcline{5}
 & & & &0&
}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Naturally, the method works inside a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[TABcline]{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
\newcommand\lminus{\llap{$-$}}
{\catcode`-=\active
\gdef -{\lminus}}
\newcommand\minusactive{\phantom{-}\catcode`-=\active}
\setstacktabbedgap{3pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll@{\hspace{10ex}}c}
1)&
$
\minusactive
\tabbedShortunderstack[r]{
 &3&7&0&5&:5=741\\
-&3&5& &&\\
\TABcline{2,3}
 & &2&0&&\\
 &-&2&0&&\\
\TABcline{3,4} 
 & & & &5&\\
 & & &-&5&\\
\TABcline{5}
 & & & &0&
}
$
&
$741\cdot5 = 3705$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That was fast.  There seem, though, to be two columns of info.

Comment: @SapharKoshet Not sure what you mean.  I just was demonstrating how to build the division.  There are various ways (using `tabular` for example) to array them in rows by columns format.

Comment: And, that you've done, and quickly.  In the example given, there's the stack segment (on the left), and what appears to be additional answer-checking in a "right column." Didn't know whether you wanted also to include that or not.

Comment: @SapharKoshet Please see revision to see how it can be done.

Comment: Yes.  That's the "right column" info.  It's possible the whole of the code you provided wasn't absorbed by the web page when the note came in.

Comment: Thank you! I have 4-5 hours on latex since yesterday and you helped me a lot!