# Modulo 2 binary long division in European notation

Tags: arithmetic

I need to represent binary modulo 2 long division in my tex document. Notation needed is same as

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division#Eurasia

under Austria, Germany, etc.

I know about longdiv package, but it doesn't seem to support this.

Is there any package to achieve this? If not, how can I manually do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can manually draw it using Ti*k*Z, but it is a bit painful, and very time-consuming if you have a lot of such divisions.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460117/other-kind-long-division-help

Answer (score 6):

The fresh new version of [`longdivision`](https://ctan.org/pkg/longdivision) package v. 1.1.0 has almost the desired output you want, with the new `german` style. As TeXlive 2018 is currently frozen, you cannot use textlive utility for updating this package, but simply download the `longdivision.sty` file from [here](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/longdivision) and add it in your local `texmf` directory or in place it along with your .tex file in the same directory.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longdivision}
\begin{document}
    \longdivision[style=german]{127}{4} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

The differences with the output from Wikipedia are :

- no negative sign displayed for the subtraction operation
- dots instead of comma for the decimal separator

The documentation show a command `\longdivdefinestyle` for modifying the display of the output, but I'm not yet able to add a negative sign for the operation, nor suppress the dots.

Comment: I'm sure your answer will make many happy users.

Answer (score 3):

The German style?? as depicted here:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[TABcline]{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\begin{document}
\tabbedShortunderstack[r]{
 &12&7& & &:\ 4\ =\ 31.75\\
-&12& & & &\\
\TABcline{2}
 & 0&7& & &\\
 & -&4& & &\\
\TABcline{3}
 &  &3&0& &\\
 & -&2&8& &\\
\TABcline{3-4}
 &  & &2&0&\\
 &  &\mathllap{-}&2&0&\\
\TABcline{4-5}
 &  & & &0&
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here, I emulate the Cyprus/France version cited in the OP's link

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[TABcline]{tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r@{}|@{}l}
\tabbedShortunderstack[r]{
 63&5&9\\
-51& &\\
\TABcline{1}
 12&5&\\
-11&9&\\
\TABcline{1-2}
   &6&9\\
  -&6&8\\
\TABcline{2-3}
   & &1
}
&
\tabbedShortunderstack[l]{
17&\\
\TABcline{1-2}
37&4
}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]